# loss of gauges on a 2003 Ford Escape

Tags: electrical

My son has a 2003 Ford Escape V6, that will all of a sudden have a loss of all gauges while he is driving and then they will come right back up with no loss of power. There has been times he has called me because his car won't start, it will turn over just fine, but, just not start. When I get there I check it with a OBD II reader and it shows no codes. After trying to start it several times it just won't fire up, then all of a sudden you try it again and it starts right up and is usually good for quite some time. As far as the gauges going off and on very quick it does that about once a week. It's got a new alternator and battery which needed to be replaced, but, it still does it. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you have at least one bad connection somewhere, but you probably guessed that yourself.  Finding it could be very difficult with it being so irregular.  If you can get a wiring diagram you may be able to narrow it down a little.  I will see what I can find.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?